# Error loading shapefile in Arcobject c# : Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040228

Tags: c#, shapefile, arcobjects

I want to read a shapefile by Arcobject and C#. I used the ArcGIS Snippet and write follow code:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(@"E:\Data\shap file iran\IRN_adm\", 0);
IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
IFeatureClass fc = fws.OpenFeatureClass("Province.shp");
```

but in line 3 returned error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040228

Whats the matter?

Comment: Did you tried `IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(@"E:\Data\shap file iran\IRN_adm\Province.shp", 0);`

Comment: Yes, I found that problem relates to license and i fixed that. but next i have problem with 
            "IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
            IFeatureClass fc = fws.OpenFeatureClass(@"E:\Data\shap file iran\IRN_adm\Province");"

Comment: I think OpenFeatureClass() should only take the featureclass name (e.g. "Province"), and not the full path or the file extension. The path you have already defined in your workspace factory.